# Using web deploy, how do you publish to a particular slot?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

I'm using web deploy (with appveyor) to publish to my web app. How can I publish to a particular slot though (i.e. staging) and not to the production slot?

What is the server url for a particular slot?

**Edit**

If the app scm is:

https://myappprod.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=myappprod

Things I've tried:

https://myappprod.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=myappprod-staging

https://myappprod-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=myappprod-staging

https://myappprod-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=myappprod

No love so far...

**Solution - For posterity**

[image]

Click the "Get publish..." button to get the publish settings for a particular slot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the publishsettings file for a specific deployment slot.  From looking at one of those, it seems the publish URL is of the form
https://myappprod-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=myappprod__staging.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I see now the download publish settings for the slot!